# How to loading animation while populating activerecord in Rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, animation, ruby-on-rails-4, chart.js

On my webpage, after the user presses a button, they are directed to another page which displays charts (using Chart.js). However, before the page is loaded I first fetch the data used to plot the charts from different server and store them into an ActiveRecord database with rails. However, this takes considerable time as there's a lot of data to be fetched.

So I am running the data fetching using a different thread (via `Thread.new do`). However, now I'm trying to solve the following problem:

When I am still fetching data to populate the database, I would like to have a loading animation (to indicated data is being fetched) and finally display the chart when all the data has been fetched.

How can I determine when my thread has finished running? And how can I tell my view that the thread has finished and should display the chart?

I've looking into gems such as Sidekiq, but they seem overkill for simply fetching data from a server.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to make view interact with controller, because view is being executed on client side, but controller is executed on server's.

What you could do is to use some jQuery code to show animation after user press the button, but before next document is loaded (without any progress being shown). 
Put div with animation element ([example](http://www.behost.es/images/loading.gif)) to you **submit** page like this:

```
<div class="progress">
some .gif here
</div>
<div class="your_content">
all other code
</div>
```

Add code like this to your application.js file

```
function showProgress() {
  $('.your_content').hide();
  $('.progress').fadeIn("slow");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.progress').hide();        //hide gif on page load    
  $('.your_button_class').on('click', showProgress); //and show it after clicking your button
});
```

Other working solutions will include relatively complicated AJAX code.
Also consider using caching for both - model and view.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and use long-polling or interval polling to determine if the job is finished. Once the job is finished it is removed from the *DelayedJobs* table so all you need to do is check if it exists. On the client-side you can initially show the animation then when the long-polling or interval polling response says that it is finished, disable the animation and show the chart.